# NTC Inrush current limiter datasheet

Tags: power-electronics, circuit-protection, thermistor, inrush-current

I have been looking at B57238S0100M0** NTC which is rated with

- R25 = 10R
- I_max = 5A
- R_min = 0.16R

I already inspected the resistance vs temperature curve and it appears to be straight forward.
However, the resistance vs current graph is rather confusing due to its discontinuity. Is it safe to assume that the resistance of 10R will remain unchanged up to 1.5A in case of B57238S0100M0** variant?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a thermistor the resistance will change due to heat which is generated by the amount of current flowing through it. The resistance at 25 degrees C will be 10 ohm and then decrease as more current is flowing through it and it heats up. So the answer is no, it will not be unchanged up until 1.5A. It would be at a higher resistance if the line on the graph were to continue/ show more data. The data it shows the operating range once it's heated up.